Quarkus container image gradle Docker
I am currently using Quarkus container image builder with Docker, but I can't find a way to get the Dockerfile.jvm and Dockerfile.native files. I manually installed Quarkus, and it worked well with Jib but as I need to add packages like buildah, I decided to use the Docker one, but there is no way to generate those two files. A lot of Docker files I see on GitHub are from four years ago and some things, for example, the container image are not the latest versions. It appears that when I try using them, it won't work.

If you just generate your project from https://code.quarkus.io/?e=rest&e=rest-jackson&e=hibernate-orm-panache&e=jdbc-postgresql you get the latest docker files under src\main\docker examples below
Dockefile.jvm
openjdk-21:1.19 released 4 months agp
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-21:1.19

ENV LANGUAGE='en_US:en'


# We make four distinct layers so if there are application changes the library layers can be re-used
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/

EXPOSE 8080
USER 185
ENV JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
ENV JAVA_APP_JAR="/deployments/quarkus-run.jar"

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh" ]

Dockerfile.native
8.9 released 4 months ago
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.9
WORKDIR /work/
RUN chown 1001 /work \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /work \
    && chown 1001:root /work
COPY --chown=1001:root target/*-runner /work/application

EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

ENTRYPOINT ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]

Looks like they are using the images from latest minus 0.1
